# Gauss sum involved in the Hecke action on classical Hilbert modular forms

Tags: modular-forms, gauss-sums, hecke-algebras, totally-real-field

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ be a real quadratic field and consider the classical Hilbert modular forms over $F$. Let $\varepsilon_0>1$ be the fundamental unit of $F$ and write $d=\varepsilon_0\sqrt{D}$. For every $a\in F$, write $a^\prime$ as its Galois conjugate.

In the book by Paul Garrett, the Hecke action on the classical Hilbert modular forms with parallel weights is defined when the narrow class number of $F$ equals $1$. If I understand correctly, the definition for $T_\mathfrak{p}$ boils down to
\begin{align*}
    (T_\mathfrak{p}f)(z)=\mathrm{N}(\mathfrak{p})^{k-1}f(pz)+\mathrm{N}(\mathfrak{p})^{-1}\sum_{\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p}}f\bigg(\frac{z+\alpha}{p}\bigg)
\end{align*}
where $p$ is a totally positive generator for $\mathfrak{p}$. And to compute the action of the Hecke operators $T_\mathfrak{p}$ on the Fourier coefficients, one should use a Gauss-like sum as the following: for any totally positive element $n\in\mathcal{O}_F$,
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p}}e^{2\pi i \big(\frac{n\alpha}{pd}+\frac{n^\prime \alpha^\prime}{p^\prime d^\prime}\big)}=\begin{cases}
    \mathrm{N}(\mathfrak{p})&\text{ if }p|n, \\
    0&\text{ if }p\nmid n.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
(One should compare this with the sum $\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi ina/p}$ for rational prime $p$ and rational integer $n$, which is needed for the elliptic modular forms.)

However, this seems to be wrong when $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(2-\sqrt{2})$. In this case, $p=2-\sqrt{2}$, $d=(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot\sqrt{2}=2+\sqrt{2}$, and $\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p}=\{0,1\}$. The sum then becomes
\begin{align*}
    1+e^{\pi i(n+n^\prime)}=2
\end{align*}
for all $n$, since $2|n+n^\prime$ regardless of whether $p$ divides $n$ or not. I am thus not sure if I make any mistake along the way.

In any case, I would truly appreciate any comments on computing the Fourier coefficients of $T_\mathfrak{p}f$ in this scenario. It would be great if there are references where the explicit computations are written down. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you perhaps accidentally omit the $d$ in the denominator (inside the exponential)?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thanks for the comment! I don't think so though, since $pd=2$ in this case, which cancels the $2$ in $2\pi i$.

Comment: I suspect it's implicit here that $D$ should be equal to the discriminant of $F$, so that the conductor of the additive character $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i (x / d + x' / d')}$ is 1. So you want to take $D = 8$ here, not $D = 2$, and that sorts things out. (There has to be some constraint on $D$, you obviously can't take $D = 2 \times 17^2$ and expect things to work.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I think you are right. It makes sense to take $D$ to be the discriminant. I think I probably mixed up the discriminant $D$ of $F$ and the $D$ in $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$. Thank you so much!